# PyGTK button event

Tags: events, button, pygtk, nameerror

I am trying to connect an event to a button and could not figure out what is wrong with my codes. Below are the source codes.

```py
import sys
import os

importStatus = False

try:
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require('2.0')
    import gtk
    importStatus = True

except ImportError:
    print "PyGTK module does not exist. Can't launch GUI !"
    print "Please download and install GTK and PyGTK."
    importStatus = False

if importStatus:

    class gtkGUI():

        output = None

        def __init__(self):
            print "Starting GTK Interface"
            self.startGUI()

        def startGUI(self):
            print "GUI Started"
            self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
            self.window.set_border_width(10)
            self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)

            ## Buttons
            self.trashbtn = gtk.Button("Trash")
            self.trashbtn.connect("clicked", self.get_trash_callback, None)

            ## Text Fields
            self.filenametf = gtk.Entry(max=0)

            ## Packing widgets into window

            # Vertical box to contain all boxes
            self.vbox = gtk.VBox(homogeneous=False, spacing=0)

            # filebox to contain file-based widgets
            self.filebox = gtk.HBox(homogeneous=False, spacing=0)
            self.filebox.pack_start(self.filenametf, expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)
            self.filebox.pack_start(self.trashbtn, expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)
            self.vbox.pack_start(self.filebox, expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)

            ## Presenting window
            self.window.add(self.vbox)
            self.window.show_all()
            gtk.main()
            return None

        def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
            return gtk.main_quit()

        def get_trash_callback(widget, event, data):
            loc = os.getenv("HOME")
            print loc + "/.local/share/Trash"
            self.filenametf.set_text(loc + "/.local/share/Trash")
```

This contains the essential codes only. If you want the actual complete codes, do notify me.

The error I received is:

```py
self.filenametf.set_text(loc + "/.local/share/Trash")
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

What I am trying to do is to connect the "Trash" button in a way that whenever clicks the "Trash" button, the filepath of a person's Linux-based Trash bin would be fetched and displayed on a Textbox or Entry field (which is the filenametf field). The problem now according to the error is the "filenametf" field could not be assessed.

How should I get about solving it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to set a "filenametf = None" after the class being defined and changed the method "get_trash_callback" parameters from "(widget, event, data)" to "(self, widget, data=None)" and it simply worked out fine without anymore problems as I intuitively just figured.